# using paramiko to send command to remote Vm but no response from openshift cluster

Tags: python, redhat, paramiko

I writing a python code which connect to remote Vm using paramiko and issue some command. I want to be able to issue a command to get pod information eg: "oc get pod".

The code works fine when sending normal Linux command eg: "df -h" and also works fine with kubectl, but when I try to send command to openShift cluster for the pod information like "oc get pod" I got no response.

script:

```
import paramiko
from time import sleep

ip_add = "IP_address"
uname = "username"
password = "password"
port = 22

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=ip_add, username=uname, password=password)

def get_pod_name(client):
    pod_name = ""
    command = 'oc get pod'

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    result = str(stdout.read().decode())
    print(stderr)

    client.close()
```

output:

```
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (EOF received) (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x9ae84b50 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>


Process finished with exit code 0
```

more details:

pyhton3.9

vm OS   - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.4 (Ootpa)

openShift cluster